# Cakephp Caching Configuration for ApcCache and Memcache

Tags: cakephp, caching, memcached, apc

I'am Using Cakephp 2.4.6 and i want use the caching in my application.
in my Bootstrap.php i found that

```
                  Cache::config('default', array('engine' => 'File'));
```

and in my core.php  i found

```
             Cache::config('_cake_core_', array(
                                      'engine' => $engine,
                                      'prefix' => $prefix . 'cake_core_',
                                      'path' => CACHE . 'persistent' . DS,
                                      'serialize' => ($engine === 'File'),
                                      'duration' => $duration
                                   ));
```

Configure the cache for model and datasource caches. This cache configuration
  is used to store schema descriptions, and table listings in connections.

```
                      Cache::config('_cake_model_', array(
                                    'engine' => $engine,
                                    'prefix' => $prefix . 'cake_model_',
                                    'path' => CACHE . 'models' . DS,
                                    'serialize' => ($engine === 'File'),
                                    'duration' => $duration
                                    ));
```

After reading the document [Cakephp Caching¶](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/caching.html#caching)
i have tried to cofigure Apc Cach in Core.php

```
                      Cache::config('default', array(
                                         'engine' => 'Apc',
                                       'duration'=> 9000,
                                           'probability'=> 100,
                                      'prefix' => Inflector::slug(APP_DIR) . '_',
                                     ));
```

it showing the error

```
  Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'CacheException' with message 
       'Cache engine default is not properly configured.' in        C:\xampp\htdocs\go4add\lib\Cake\Cache\Cache.php:181 Stack trace: #0
```

then i tried  it to configuring in bootstrap.php , same effect.
Please help me..i am confusing..

**Is there any Installation needed form Apc Cache and memcache in cakephp?**
***if needed please tel me how to Instal Apc i nCakeph***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't touch any thing. Just change the `$engine = 'File';` to `$engine = 'Apc';` at core.php on line 352. And don't forget to install Apc.